# Virsh - Autostart VM Upon Network Bootup

Tags: centos, networking, virtual-machine, virsh

I started my first VM using a script my apprentice made.  After a few days my graphics card froze so I had to reboot the server.  Upon restart, I can see `virsh list --all` shows the VM I set up but the state is `shut off`.

```
$  virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 -     centos7.0-li                   shut off
```

Fine, so I started it us with `virsh start centos7.0-li` and now the VM is running.

Question is how do I set it so the VM will automatically start upon network boot up?

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
virsh autostart centos7.0-li
```

Comment: I see, domain = vm.  The command went through thanks.  How do I get the terminal of the vm to come up now?

Comment: @JesseWilliamMacDougall that should be `virsh console centos7.0-li` or start with detached console `virsh autostart centos7.0-li --console`

Comment: I ran "virsh console centos7.0-li" and got "Connected to domain centos7.0-li" I see the cursor blinking but no gui came up.  A colleague made this script up the other day, not sure if this is interfering https://paste.linux.community/view/5ec9a1af